# Buscando un verbo que encaje mejor con "ahora me encanta solo un poco, luego me encantará más"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, expresiones, solicitud-de-término

Este fin de semana he tenido un pequeño diálogo con mi hijo mayor que me dejó pensando en cómo plantear aquí la duda que me generó. Así que vamos allá. El caso es que al salir de un centro comercial le sacamos de una [máquina expendedora de pelotas sorpresa](http://www.compravending.com/bd/anuncios/200810161139200.Giant_Superball_Aluminio.jpg) una pelotita de goma de las que botan mucho, y cuando volvíamos a casa en el coche intercambiamos este par de frases:

> —¿Qué, te gusta la pelotita que te ha tocado?
>   —Sí, me encanta, pero ahora me encanta solo un poquito, luego en casa cuando pueda jugar con ella me encantará más.

Esa frase que me soltó hizo que me chirriaran un poco las neuronas porque claro, cuando algo te gusta no lo haces depender del tiempo, dado que sabes que antes o después podrás jugar con ese juguete. Es el concepto tras la expresión *hacer ilusión*: la esperanza de poder pasártelo bien con algo en el futuro. Sin embargo, él vive el presente y no estaba contento en ese momento porque no podía jugar con la pelota al ir en el coche, y expresó que en casa estaría más contento.

El caso es que en ese momento no supe decirle a mi hijo qué verbo o expresión tenía que usar que encajara mejor con lo que él quería decir. ¿Qué pensáis? ¿Dais por buena su frase? ¿Creéis que se hizo entender bien? ¿Cómo se podría mejorar? ¿Qué verbo encajaría mejor con el concepto que él estaba intentando expresar? ¿O sería mejor reordenar la frase y expresarla de otra forma diferente?

Comment: Me hace pensar en una frase que he oído, pero que me choca: "I'm a bit exhausted."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te descuadra en el uso de *encantar* es que, en este contexto, conlleva ya de por sí una gradación de *gustar*:

> [**encantar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ez09pdw#MqvkkSn)
>   Del lat. *incantāre*.
>
> 4. intr. Gustar **en gran medida**, agradar **mucho**. *Le encanta el cine.*

Entonces, decir *«me encanta solo un poquito»* es decir *«me gusta mucho solo un poco»*, lo cual es contradictorio. Es necesario eliminar la gradación implícita, usando un verbo más básico (**gustar**, **agradar**) que pueda aceptar los adverbios *mucho/poco* de manera pura.

De lo anterior se sigue que sí sería válido [**gustar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JueNX6F#8eL41LU):

> *—¿Qué, te gusta la pelotita que te ha tocado?*
>   *—Sí, **me gusta**, pero ahora **me gusta** solo un poquito, luego en casa cuando pueda jugar con ella **me gustará** más.*

Aunque lo descartes en tu pregunta, no comparto la afirmación de que *«cuando algo te gusta no lo haces depender del tiempo»*: muy pocas cosas nos gustan siempre, ya que hay muchas que no conocemos y otras que nos acaban cansando; y en especial las cosas nuevas nos pueden ir gustando cada vez más o cada vez menos conforme las vamos descubriendo y explorando.

En el caso de tu hijo, acabas de comprarle esta pelota y de momento lo único que conoce de ella son sus colores, su tacto, la **alegría** que le supone que su papá se la haya regalado... Eso le gusta; pero no puede jugar con ella, por tanto el **disfrute** no es completo.

Y así, discretamente, he introducido otras dos posibilidades, que serían [**disfrutar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DusQUW3):

> *—¿Qué, te gusta la pelotita que te ha tocado?*
>   *—Sí, **disfruto** con ella* [con sus colores, su forma, con saber que tengo una pelota nueva]*, pero ahora **disfruto** solo un poquito, luego en casa cuando pueda jugar con ella **disfrutaré** más.*

O simplemente [**alegrarse**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1hHpisE#0kKTVns):

> *—¿Qué, te gusta la pelotita que te ha tocado?*
>   *—Sí, **me alegra*** [tenerla]*, pero ahora **me alegra** solo un poquito, luego en casa cuando pueda jugar con ella **me alegrará** más.*

Comment: ¡Gran respuesta! Tienes razón, los gustos varían con el tiempo. Creo que aún tenía en la cabeza el verbo "encantar" y escribí la frase con "gustar" y, como se ve en tu respuesta, la cosa cambia si usas uno u otro.

Comment: Yo solo agregaría que es posible establecer una escala de verbos con graduación implícita por ejemplo para expresar el placer que nos causa determinada actividad la escala sería de menor a mayor: "lo tolero", "me es indiferente", "me agrada", "me gusta", "me encanta", "me fascina", "me enloquece", "me flipa", "lo amo", "lo adoro". Es común escuchar modismos que combinan 3 niveles para subrayar la superlatividad inequívocamente: ¿Te gusta la ensalada? -que va! Me fascina, me encanta, me enloquece! Que es una bonita forma de ser correctamente redundante sin cacofonia.

Answer (score 1):

Como expresión de un niño preescolar (si mal no recuerdo la edad de tu hijo), o incluso de un niño de edad escolar, me parece perfectamente bien.

Ahora, si imagino los papeles al revés (tu hijo encuentra algo y te lo ofrece como regalo, y te pregunta se te gusta), entonces puedo proponer una alternativa para tí -- decir

> —Sí, me encanta.  En casa cuando pueda jugar con ella me encantará más aún.

Perdón, no te propuse un *verbo*, como pediste, sino un adverbio.

Comment: Nada que perdonar, también me valen formas de reordenar la frase para que encaje mejor.